# How can I use typescript generics for dynamic function arguments

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, grpc

I am trying to create a *wrapper* method around [node's gRPC bindings](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/node.html). I'd like to make a method called `rpc` on `WrapperClient` that invokes a method on the underlying `GrpcClient` class but also type check both the **method** and the **request** arguments.

Here is an example I'll cross post to the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ReqA%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20'a'%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20ReqB%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20'b'%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PeopleServiceClient%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20findA(request%3A%20ReqA)%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20findB(request%3A%20ReqB)%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20WrapperClient%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rpc%3CPeopleServiceClient%2C%20TMethod%20extends%20keyof%20PeopleServiceClient%3E(client%3A%20PeopleServiceClient%2C%20method%3A%20TMethod%2C%20req%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20grpcClient%20%3D%20new%20PeopleServiceClient()%0D%0Aconst%20client%20%3D%20new%20WrapperClient()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20works%0D%0A%0D%0AgrpcClient.findA(%7B%20type%3A%20'a'%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0AgrpcClient.findB(%7B%20type%3A%20'b'%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20doesn't.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20It%20Matches%20the%20method%20name.%20That's%20good.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20It%20does%20not%20check%20the%20request%20type%20though.%0D%0A%0D%0Aclient.rpc(grpcClient%2C%20'findA'%2C%201)%20%2F%2F%20should%20fail%0D%0Aclient.rpc(grpcClient%2C%20'findB'%2C%201)%20%2F%2F%20should%20fail%0D%0Aclient.rpc(grpcClient%2C%20'findC'%2C%201)%20%2F%2F%20%2B1%20for%20the%20method%20check%0D%0A%0D%0A).

```
type ReqA = { type: 'a' }
type ReqB = { type: 'b' }

class GrpcClient {
    findA(request: ReqA) { };
    findB(request: ReqB) { };
}

class WrapperClient {
    rpc<GrpcClient, TMethod extends keyof GrpcClient>(client: GrpcClient, method: TMethod, req: any) {
    }
}

const grpcClient = new GrpcClient()
const client = new WrapperClient()

// This works

grpcClient.findA({ type: 'a' }) // correct
grpcClient.findB({ type: 'b' }) // correct

// This doesn't.
// It Matches the method name. That's good.
// But it does not check the request type.

client.rpc(grpcClient, 'findA', 1) // should fail
client.rpc(grpcClient, 'findB', 1) // should fail
client.rpc(grpcClient, 'findC', 1) // double fail, the method check works though
```

I'm able to use the `extends keyof` generic expression to typecheck the method names. I'm not able to type check the request arguments though.

I could hard code a union as the request argument type.

```
    rpc<GrpcClient, TMethod extends keyof GrpcClient>(client: GrpcClient, method: TMethod, req: ReqA | ReqB) {
```

The gRPC bindings are dynamically generated and I don't want to maintain a list of possible request types that could change when I regenerate the bindings.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to determine the request type:

```
type ReqA = { type: 'a' }
type ReqB = { type: 'b' }

class PeopleServiceClient {
    findA(request: ReqA) { };
    findB(request: ReqB) { };
}

class WrapperClient {
    rpc<PeopleServiceClient, TMethod extends keyof PeopleServiceClient>(
        client: PeopleServiceClient, method: TMethod,
        req: PeopleServiceClient[TMethod] extends (arg: infer T) => void ? T : never) {
    }
}

const grpcClient = new PeopleServiceClient()
const client = new WrapperClient()

grpcClient.findA({ type: 'a' }) // correct
grpcClient.findB({ type: 'b' }) // correct

client.rpc(grpcClient, 'findA', {type: 'a'}) // correct
client.rpc(grpcClient, 'findA', {type: 'b'}) // fails
client.rpc(grpcClient, 'findA', 1) // fails
client.rpc(grpcClient, 'findB', 1) // fails
client.rpc(grpcClient, 'findC', 1) // fails
```